# How can I trigger component that doesn't have relation to render again?

Tags: reactjs

I have a `Header` component, which will display the dropdown Sign in, Sign up, and a Logout in a Navbar. Which will count as Component A.

And I also have `Sign In` Component, which is considered Component B in my ways of thought. It'll display a box of Sign in with field and a Login button in the content body.

What do I want to achieve? If I log in -> I will receive a token, and If at the header, I have a token, it'll display only the Logout, if token = null, it'll only display Sign in and Sign up.

What I have achieved?

If I press logout from the header - which is the dropdown navbar, I can set the state for the token to `null`, so the state change, it'll render the component again, which will update and display the Sign-up and Sign-in since token = `null` because I remove the token in `localStorage`

The problem is:

That doesn't work with the `Sign-in` component, since it from a completely different component, it doesn't have any relation with the header. If I press the Log in button from the `Sign In` component, I can get the Token and push it into the localStorage, but I have to manually refresh the web page so it can render again, I can't find a way to pass that token into the header so it can receive as a state to make it render again.

I need help, thanks. I think there's a way, which is using Redux or something to store the state, but I don't know how to use it, so please, is there any way I can do this using only React?

`Header` component:

```
export default function Header(props) {
    const [token, setToken] = useState(localStorage.getItem("token"));
    const onClickToSignOut = () => {
        localStorage.removeItem("token");
        setToken(null);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        setToken(token);
    }, [token]);

    return (
        <div className="header">
            <div className="logo">
                <img src="./Demo/assets/images/logo.png" alt="SCC Logo" />
            </div>
            <ul id="nav">
                <li>
                    <Link to="/">Home</Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <Link to="/contact">Contact</Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <Link to="/quiz-topics">Quiz Topic</Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <i className="ti-user"></i>
                    </a>
                    <ul className="subnav">
                        {!token ? (
                            <>
                                <li>
                                    <Link to="/sign-in">Sign in </Link>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <Link to="/sign-up">Sign up</Link>
                                </li>
                            </>
                        ) : (
                            <>
                                <li>
                                    <Link to="/sign-in" onClick={onClickToSignOut}>
                                        Log out
                                    </Link>
                                </li>
                            </>
                        )}
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div id="mobile-menu" className="mobile-menu-btn">
                <i className="menu-icon ti-menu"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

The `SignIn` component:

```
class SignIn extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            username: "",
            password: "",
        };
    }

    handleOnChange = (event) => {
        let { name, value } = event.target;

        this.setState({
            [name]: value,
        });
    };

    handleOnSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        let { username, password } = this.state;
        if (username === "" && password === "") {
            toast.warning(`Please enter all the fields`);
        } else if (username === "") {
            toast.error(`Please enter your username`);
        } else if (password === "") {
            toast.error(`Please enter your password`);
        } else {
            callApi("sign-in", "POST", {
                username: username,
                password: password,
            }).then((res) => {
                if (res.data.token) {
                    localStorage.setItem("token", res.data.token);
                    this.setState({ token: res.data.token });
// I want to do something in here that can trigger the Header component after I receive the token when I'm pressing submit at the login//
                    toast.success(`Successfully log in.`);
                    this.props.history.push("/");
                } else {
                    toast.error(`There is something wrong, please try again.`);
                }
            });
        }
    };
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="register-page height-fixed">
                <div id="toast"></div>
                <div
                    style={{
                        background:
                            "url('/Demo/assets/images/slider/slider1.jpg'), no-repeat, fixed, center",
                        height: "100vh",
                    }}
                >
                    <div className="register-section vertical-center">
                        <h2>Sign in</h2>
                        <div className="user-info">
                            <form onSubmit={this.handleOnSubmit}>
                                <div className="row">
                                    <div className="username-line">
                                        <div className="col-25">
                                            <label htmlFor="username">Username</label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="col-75">
                                            <input
                                                onChange={this.handleOnChange}
                                                type="text"
                                                placeholder="Enter username"
                                                name="username"
                                                value={this.state.username}
                                            />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div className="row">
                                    <div className="password-line">
                                        <div className="col-25">
                                            <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="col-75">
                                            <input
                                                onChange={this.handleOnChange}
                                                type="password"
                                                placeholder="Enter password"
                                                name="password"
                                                value={this.state.password}
                                            />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div className="user-info-button">
                                    <Link to="/sign-up">
                                        <button className="btn btn--success btn--danger">
                                            Sign up
                                        </button>
                                    </Link>

                                    <button type="submit">Log in</button>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default SignIn;
```

Comment: Share your header and Sign-in component code please. You need to store the token somewhere in top level so that All (Or in this case both) component can access it via props.

Comment: and are you using any state-management library, like redux?

Comment: Wait a minute, I'll post the code, and sorry, I don't use any state-management library, because I don't know how to use it.

Comment: No problem, you don't have to use redux, if you don't want to. i was just asking to confirm.

Comment: The `Sign-in` component I write is in class component, which I studied how to write class component at first, and the `Header` I write it in functional component way since I find the useEffect is easier to use than the componentDidMount and shorter. I updated the code. So please understandable :)

Comment: I would suggest, use context for this no need to use any external lib for state management if you are not using it. Check this how you can handle global state
https://devsmitra.medium.com/state-management-with-react-hooks-and-context-api-2968a5cf5c83

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at it, I don't know if I can manage to use it, because I've never used this context before.

Comment: Yes, you need to use context. if you haven't used it before it's good time to learn the context API. it's very useful.

Comment: I'll suggest try to understand the concept, It''ll help you in long run.

Comment: Thanks, @GulamHussain, I'm reading it right now :)